# what is this green thing?

Tags: hidamari-sketch

Maybe it's my fault for not watching from the first season, but I'm wondering, what exactly is this? it already appear in the very first episode in Hidamari Sketch × ☆☆☆ (Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi Mittsu), was he ever introduced in the anime?

[image: figure in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Ume sensei dressed as a Pokemon (metapod). Ume sensei is voiced by [Ume Aoki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ume_Aoki), the manga artist.

Comment: And here I always thought that it was just the caterpillar Yuno was raising!

Comment: So I guess he never introduced in the anime